# Regex to check number starts with '078' and only contains 10 digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, textbox

I need to validate a Textbox in my Asp.Net application where the user can enter mobile number and it should starts with 078 and should contain 10 digits.

**Sample:**

0781234567

here is my code

```
 public static  bool  CheckPhoneNum(string strPhoneNumber)
    {
        string MatchPhoneNumberPattern = "/^(?=\\d{10,11}$)(07)\\d+/";
        if (strPhoneNumber!= null) return Regex.IsMatch(strPhoneNumber, MatchPhoneNumberPattern );
        else return false;
    }
```

but it always returns false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you try this? The below regex would validate for phone numbers which should be starts with `078` followed by any 7 digit number.

```
^078\d{7}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vC2yW4/9)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `078` Matches exactly the digits `078`.
- `\d{7}` Matches the following 7 digits.
- `$` End of the line.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Gd8zFI)

Comment: if you dont mind, can you tell me where you have validated 10 digits?

Comment: `078`-three digits , `\d{7}` - 7 digits . Total 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
^078[0-9]{7}$
```

This is a bit faster than `\d` if we use only numbers here.