# Regular expression to check the starting character of the string and length of the string

Tags: regex

I have written below regular expression to check the length of the string, which works well https://regex101.com/r/5ra1eU/3

```
  \b[0-9]{6}$
```

Now, I wish to check if the number starts with the digit `4` only and have only `6` digits

Example:

- 412345  - Right number
- 4123456 - Wrong number
- 123456  - Wrong number

I tried with `^` but did not work

Comment: Use `^4[0-9]{5}$`

Comment: wow, works! Please add it in a solution so that I can mark it as the answer!

Comment: This has been asked many times, I closed with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104987/regex-to-check-number-starts-with-078). This is more a logical issue. Also, `^` is working well, no need of word boundaries.